# Why does my method always return null?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, webclient

```
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
  <Copyright>Copyright &#xA9; 2011 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights
   reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results
   may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express
   written permission from Microsoft Corporation.</Copyright>
  <BrandLogoUri>[http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png]</BrandLogoUri>
  <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
  <StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
  <AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
  <TraceId>50230e70257e4ed5a5002a3d4a625c83|LTSM001156|02.00.159.1700|LTSMSNVM001471, LTSMSNVM001477</TraceId>
  <ResourceSets>
    <ResourceSet>
      <EstimatedTotal>1</EstimatedTotal>
      <Resources>
        <Location>
          <Name>1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052</Name>
          <Point>
            <Latitude>47.640568390488625</Latitude>
            <Longitude>-122.1293731033802</Longitude>
          </Point>
          <BoundingBox>
            <SouthLatitude>47.636705672917948</SouthLatitude>
            <WestLongitude>-122.137016420622</WestLongitude>
            <NorthLatitude>47.6444311080593</NorthLatitude>
            <EastLongitude>-122.1217297861384</EastLongitude>
          </BoundingBox>
          <EntityType>Address</EntityType>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine>1 Microsoft Way</AddressLine>
            <AdminDistrict>WA</AdminDistrict>
            <AdminDistrict2>King Co.</AdminDistrict2>
            <CountryRegion>United States</CountryRegion>
            <FormattedAddress>1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052</FormattedAddress>
            <Locality>Redmond</Locality>
            <PostalCode>98052</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Confidence>Medium</Confidence>
        </Location>
      </Resources>
    </ResourceSet>
  </ResourceSets>
</Response>
```

My query formerly looked like:

```
private void getData()
{
    // Api letőltése
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    string url = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/" 
                 + _location + "?o=xml&key=App-asdf";

    webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                return;

            XDocument xmlLocation = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");
            var locality = from q in xmlLocation.Descendants(ns + "Address")
                           select (string)q.Element(ns + "Locality").Value;
        };

    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
}
```

Why does it always return `null`?

I want to query the locality but my variable always contains `null`. I recently wrote a similar program code which worked but now have a namespace and don't understand what the problem would be.

Comment: try to remove `ns + `. Will it work?

Comment: As Henk I tried your posted XML with the query you posted and it finds data. So there must be a difference between your posted samples and the ones you use or get when you run your code. One possible issue could be a change in the namespace, you might be able to avoid that by doing `XNamespace ns = xmlLocation.Root.Name.Namespace;` instead of hardcoding the URL as you currently do. Also note that `select (string)q.Element(ns + "Locality").Value` should be shortened to either `select (string)q.Element(ns + "Locality")` or `select q.Element(ns + "Locality").Value`, there is no need for both.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your query against the listed XML and it produces "Redmond".

So: Break it down. You have a communication or threading problem.

```
    if (e.Error != null)
                return;
```

Is a good way to sweep the problem under the rug.

Answer (score 0):

```
var locality = xmlLocation.Descendants(ns + "Locality").Select( x => x.Value);
```